# Change Fused Location priority during runtime

Tags: android, google-play, android-fusedlocation

I have two intent services:
1. receives location updates in the background using Fused Location API.
2. Receives Activity Recognition in the background using Activity Recognition API.

whenever i detect that the user is standing still i want to be able to change the priority of fused location from PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY to PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY.

I heard about removeLocationUpdates() and then calling to requestLocationUpdates() but i cant use that since im only running intent services without activity in the background.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: Why can't you call `requestLocationUpdates()` from within your activity recognition `IntentService`?

Comment: Because GoogleApiClient is not connected there and the intent service doesnt know about GoogleApiClient Object at all ... is ther any way i can send that object from the activity to the intent service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app can connect to `GoogleApiClient` in more than one place at the same time. It will be much easier on yourself to connect to a `GoogleApiClient` with [`blockingConnect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) in your activity recognition `IntentService` such that you can call [`requestLocationUpdates()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) directly when you need to.

Note the comment on `requestLocationUpdates()` Javadoc:

> Any previously registered requests that have the same PendingIntent (as defined by [equals(Object)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#equals(java.lang.Object))) will be replaced by this request.

So there should not be a need to call `removeLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: Thanks ... So you are saying to make a new connection to GoogleApiClient in the Activity Recognition intent service and just to request whenever i need to ?